# Need to know the meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idioms, slang

Recently I watched "*The Power Of The Dog*" movie. In that movie, Phil, the main character was telling his brother "*you could take her out without putting sack over her head.*"

So I need to know, what does he mean by that?

Comment: I haven't seen the film in question, but it's very likely to be "without putting **a** sack over her head".

Answer (score 5):

He means that the woman being discussed is not so ugly that her face needs to be concealed: she is attractive.

Of course, it's a figure of speech, not literal.

Comment: thank you sir for your reply, it means so much.

Comment: You are welcome, sir.

Comment: @RavinduRukshan, If Jack has answered your question you can accept his answer by clicking on the green tick next to his answer. Or you can wait to see if a better answer is written.

Comment: @RavinduRukshan - many people in Western countries would say this is a nasty, stupid,  and unpleasant way to talk about women.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Yes it is.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - thinking about it [not just Western countries](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-20863860#:~:text=Clearly%2C%20many%20Indian%20women%20face,women%20more%20accepted%20and%20secure.).

Comment: Wow, obviously context matters. Having not seen the movie, I thought for sure it meant "You could take her out [kill her] without putting a sack over her head [she will be killed so you don't have to worry if she already knows your face]"

Comment: @BruceWayne - charming! Murdering women or if not, bagging their heads. Maybe the dialog was intended to be seen as stupid or immature?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The movie takes place a century ago and the characters are cowboys. This seems like typical "guy talk" from this period. A more modern idiom would be something like "I wouldn't kick her out of bed."

Comment: @Barmar ... for eating crackers.